# Grant access to multiple databases via Azure AD in sql database

Tags: sql-server, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

**Description**

We use Azure SQL database with multiple databases on a server. It is possible to grant permissions to a single database via the user's Azure AD login by creating a group, say "DBReader". in AAD and assign the group to the role "Reader" via the server's settings in azure portal and then create a *user* when connected to the database as `CREATE USER [DBReaders] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER`, which will allow connecting to the single database.

**Problem**

We'd like to grant read access to *all* databases, so that the user sees all databases with a single connection and must not add them separately. Normally, you'd create a login on the server for this. However, the preview feature https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-mi-current, which would allow `CREATE LOGIN ... FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER` is not available for Azure SQL database.

**Question**

Is there any way we did not think of to simply grant access to all databases via an AAD group?

Comment: If you want this functionality (and other on-premises functionality), Managed Instance may be a better fit. But what is the actual issue with granting the same AAD group access to multiple databases?

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, the problem is that we then must add connections for each database separately (e.g. management studio, linqpad), as one must specify the DB on connect if it is a per-database user. A suitable solution would involve the user to being able to see all databases he has permissions to at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way we did not think of to simply grant access to all databases via an AAD group?

No.  Outside of Managed Instance, which requires a minimum of [4 vCores](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/general-availability-4-vcore-azure-sql-database-managed-instances-on-gen5/), Azure SQL Database users must be added to each database.

> A suitable solution would involve the user to being able to see all databases he has permissions to at once

For Azure SQL Database, this requires the client to connect to Master to, and then reconenct to switch databases.  [SQL Server Management Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) does this, but other clients may not.

Comment: I tried to create a user for the master database on that server (`CREATE USER [Group name] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER`), which works just fine. However, I fail to assign the user to the `db_datareader` group, so that the connection is denied.

Comment: There's no user data in the master database, so no need to add database-level permissions.

Comment: Indeed. However, I still had to create the user on the master database. This was sufficient for the user to login via AAD and actually see all databases. Only those databases with dedicated read permissions are expandable, though. So exactly what I wanted, thank you.